# Is there any way to access Google Plus Messenger history?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-plus, google-plus-huddles

Once you leave a Google Plus Messenger (formerly Huddle) conversation, it is removed from the main window of the application. Is there any way to view or search old messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is irrelevant now as Google have moved messenger to [Hangouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk).

Hangouts does have message archiving. From the list of hangouts, select options in the top right corner. Then select Archived Hangouts.